# Active directory integration issue with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, active-directory

The active Directory login is not working for us on DMZ server since the request is going to multiple domain controllers servers (which cause us slowness in login- almost 10 minutes). how can we limit it to only one DC server?

Jenkins version: 2.176.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had to mention the specific DC on the Site field